# node js + async parallel + function call method not working

Tags: node.js

I have functions in different place.(this is common function it will use many place.
So I tried to call the function using async parallel but its not working. 
I attached the my code following:L

```
var userId = 33;

async.parallel({
        video(userId, callback) {
            callback(null, callback);
        },
        video1(userId, callback) {
            callback(null, callback);
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });



    function video (userId, callback) {
        client.query("select youtube_id,title,id,thumbnail,search_item from resource order by random() limit 1 ", function(err, video) {
            callback(err, video);
        });

    }

    function video1(userId, callback) {
            client.query("select youtube_id,title,id,thumbnail,search_item from resource1 order by random() limit 1 ", function(err, video1) {
                callback(err, video1);
            });

        }
```

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript.  What is meant by `function name : function`?

Comment: Sorry, Already I am used like  var videofunction =  { video : function () { }, video1 : function () {... } }; So I copied that code and paste. Now I changed

Answer (score 0):

The `{fnName()}` syntax is a function declaration. You want to use a function call ... in fact you can just use `async.parallel({video, video1}, (err, results) => console.log(results)` to achieve the same effect... except that you also need to pass in `userId`. So what you actually intend is to *call* the function rather than declare it:

```
async.parallel([
    callback => video(userId, callback),
]);
```

Comment: I tried like the following:                                                                             ** * async.parallel([
  callback = globaldetails.video(userId, callback),
], function(err, results) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(results);
}); *** but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass function references to `async.parallel()` and you need to pass an array, not an object.   You want the code to have this form:

```
async.parallel([fn1, fn2], finalCallback);
```

See the [`async.parallel()` doc here](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback) for specific examples of the syntax you want to use.

Where `fn1`, `fn2` and `finalCallback` are all function references that can be called by the `async.parallel()` infrastructure, not something you call yourself.

Change your code to this:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        client.query("select youtube_id,title,id,thumbnail,search_item from resource order by random() limit 1 ", function(err, video) {
            callback(err, video);
        }),
    }, 
    function(callback) {
        client.query("select youtube_id,title,id,thumbnail,search_item from resource order by random() limit 1 ", function(err, video1) {
            callback(err, video1);
        });
    }
], function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
});
```

Presumably, your two database queries should be different somehow (your code showed them identical).

If your functions are already defined somewhere, then you can pass an anonymous function reference that will call them.  You need to do this if your functions don't have the exact same calling convention that `async.parallel()` requires.  You can do that like this:

```
 async.parallel([function(callback) {
          video(userId, callback);
      }, function(callback) {
          video1(userId, callback);
      }], function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);
 });
```

Comment: I expect the answer,how to access the function value using the async.parrllel , because function video and video1 is using many places.

Comment: @RSKMR - I've added an example of how you would call functions that are already defined.  You should be able to see this from the async examples in their doc also.